# unkown android icon

Tags: android-versions, notification-icons

I saw this icon and I wanted to know what application it belongs to (it is in the gray area, not the top bar):

[image: screenshot]

Comment: specify which icon? icons on status bar or the middle one?

Comment: If you mean the first one, its for the battery #D Honestly, Bob, you must be a bit more specific. Raw guess, you're asking for the second-to-last icon in the notification bar (the one with 4 dots)? Must be some BlackBerry app. Being on the right, it seems to be a system app. What's your device (probably some BB?) and Android version?

Comment: @Izzy or does he mean the one in the gray box with three curving lines?

Comment: We will never know unless Bob [edit]s and updates the question accordingly. Which is why I'll put it on hold now as "unclear".

Comment: The icon is the Swiftkey Keyboard logo.

Comment: @Izzy someone commented on what the icon is

Comment: @MarkYisri what *which* icon is? It's neither clear which icon Bob is asking for, nor which icon esComo refers to.

Comment: I am sorry I meant the swiftketly, which escosmo has qlanswered on.

Comment: @Izzy it can be reopened now

Comment: @esQmo You obviously guesses the right one. Mind to post an answer (with a reference, if you have one), and we clean up the comments here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The icon with 6-curved lines is the logo of [Swiftkey keyboard](https://swiftkey.com/en/keyboard/android). 
[image]